# Codeigniter not showing data and page is not showing

Tags: codeigniter

My `codeigniter` is not showing page.

**Model**

```
function get_all_district_circulars()
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('district_circulars');
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller index function**

```
public function index()
{
    $dt['dist_circulars'] = $this->content_model->get_all_district_circulars();
    $this->load->view('parts/top');
    $this->load->view('parts/header');
    $this->load->view('parts/nav');
    $this->load->view('district_circulars', $dt);
    $this->load->view('parts/footer');
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
    foreach($dist_circulars as $dt_circulars){
?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php

    }
?>
```

If I delete this `foreach` function, the page is displaying properly, but if I put it, the page is not loading and showing `This site can’t be reached` and Chrome console shows `GET http://localhost/anandadhara/district_circulars/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

What should I do ?

**UPDATE 1**

My `.htaccess` as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /anandadhara/   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I am using wampserver 2.2

**UPDATE 2**

My file name is `district_circulars.php`.

`CLASS`:

```
class District_circulars extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('content_model');
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

It works fine if I display a single result here.

```
<?php
    foreach($dist_circulars as $dt_circulars){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dt_circulars->id; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php

    }
?>
```

But if I show more than 1 field here like...

```
<td><?php echo $dt_circulars->id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $dt_circulars->memo_no; ?></td>
```

Or even if I put only two blank html tag here...

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

The page shows ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and showing browser blank page with `connection_reset` page and showing no data.

I cannot understand what is going on here.

Comment: it seems you missed loading model. `$this->load->model('content_model');`

Comment: No, I loaded my model `$this->load->model('content_model');` in `public function __construct(){}`

Comment: try to `var_dump($dt); die;` after `$dt['dist_circulars'] = $this->content_model->get_all_district_circulars();`. It might returning empty.

Comment: It seems like `.htaccess` issue. Can you please share your `.htaccess` code.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya plz see the update

Comment: Make sure you have followed the codeigniter file and class naming way as said here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Hi @wolfgang1983, my filename and class name is ok as per the documentation.

Comment: at removing the `foreach` every thing working fine. so the problem must be with in the data he iterating. I don't think it could be `.htaccess` or naming convention problem.

Comment: So what to do ? my `var_dump($dt); die;` is not empty. it is showing data

Comment: Then before foreach loop you can use `isset($dist_circulars)`

Comment: can you please update the ```var_dump``` data in question?

Comment: Try to add `parent::__construct();` in constructor, before loading model.

Comment: One last thing I can suggest you is in your view you need to use `$dt_circulars->field_name` hope you have not used `$dt_circulars['field_name']`. Because as per above comments you are getting data in `$dist_circulars` inside view file, Then might be you have done this operator mistake in `foreach` loop iteration. And also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in controller, so you can get error

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya plz see the last update

Answer (score 0):

Model:

//need to make it a public function if calling from controller

```
public function get_all_district_circulars()
{
 //simplify your model call, use get instead of from
 return $this->db->select('*')->where('status', 1)->order_by('id', 'desc')->get('district_circulars')->result();


}
```

View:

place an if check and also use php alternative syntax when in the views
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?php if(isset($dist_circulars)): ?>

  <?php foreach($dist_circulars as $dt_circulars): ?>


    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```